# Floor of Bais Hamikdash

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash

There is a story in the Talmud that one Kohen noticed a discoloration of the tiles on the floor and figured it was where the place where the Ark was buried. He went to notify his fellow Kohanim and before he could do that he died.

Does anyone know where that Gemorah is?

Answer (score 8):

It's the [Mishna Shekalim 6:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shekalim.6.2?lang=bi).

> מעשה בכהן אחד שהיה מתעסק וראה הרצפה שהיא משונה מחברותיה בא ואמר לחברו
>   לא הספיק לגמור את הדבר עד שיצתה נשמתו וידעו ביחוד ששם הארון נגנז:‏
>   It once happened that a priest was preoccupied, and he saw that the
>   [part of the] floor was different from its neighbors. He came and told
>   his fellow. He did not finish telling his fellow before he died, and
>   they knew for certain that the Ark was hidden there.